# How to check lat or long value is in the MapView region

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

How to check the latitude and the longitude value is laying on the MapView region or outside the MapView region.

Answer (score 0):

```
        //This is outside render funtion 

    handleItem = (lat, lng) => {
    this.setState({ latitude: lat, longitude: lng })
    this.map.animateToCoordinate({ latitude: lat, longitude: lng }, 1000)
                         }



                     //this is is in render function

                 <MapView style={{ flex: 1 }}
                    ref={map => this.map = map}
                    initialRegion={{
                        latitude: this.state.latitude,
                        longitude: this.state.longitude,
                        latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
                        longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
                    }}>
                    <Marker coordinate={this.state} />
             { this.handleItem(this.state.latitude, this.state.longitude) }}
                </MapView>
```

Comment: It's just basic code. For creating a MapView.  I created a RN app where the marker is moving live.. What i want.. When the marker is in near the corners of the MapView then my MapView region should be update so that i can see marker as long as it's moving

Comment: adjust this code i dont have time to run this but i have done this code to apply animation when location is changed